# Eclipse - "Error moving resource"

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, service, web

I am creating a web service client to consume a WCF service in eclipse and when I enter in the url for my WSDL, the setup wizard begins generating classes, then abruptly stops and spits out a nasy error message specifically targeting one of my classes.

```
IWAB0523E Error moving resource: Could not read from source when writing file 'C:\Documents and Settings\sam.bengtson\My Documents\Java Files\WebServiceProject\src\org\datacontract\schemas\_2004\_07\InmateCanteenService\CallStatus.java'
```

The thing is, this class is automatically generated by the .Net connector for MySql.  This also used to work without any problems and I have not recently changed my WCF service either.  Has anybody else seen this error message before?  Any sort of help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing your project and then cleaning it.

Comment: Thinking that this was the problem, I created a fresh project and created a new service client but still got the same error.  I'm not quite sure why eclipse can't generate the classes anymore.

Comment: I'm with the very same problem. But, as said, it's not due to old version of files. There is something specific with this WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has no idea about file modification that has taken place outside of it. The problem could simply be that you need to refresh the project which would involve selecting the project name and hitting `F5` or right-click and select `Refresh`.

Comment: Thinking that this was the problem, I created a fresh project and created a new service client but still got the same error.  I'm not quite sure why eclipse can't generate the classes anymore.